# Finding the global minimum of a noisy function via simulated annealing in python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I'm trying to find the global minimum of the function from the hundred digit hundred dollars challenge, question #4 as an exercise for simulated annealing.

As the basis of my understanding and approach to writing the code, I refer to the global optimization algorithms version 3 book which is found for free online.

Consequently, I've initially come up with the following code:

The noisy func:

```py
def noisy_func(x, y):
    return (math.exp(math.sin(50*x)) +
            math.sin(60*math.exp(y)) +
            math.sin(70*math.sin(x)) +
            math.sin(math.sin(80*y)) -
            math.sin(10*(x + y)) +
            0.25*(math.pow(x, 2) +
            math.pow(y, 2)))
```

The function used to mutate the values:

```py
def mutate(X_Value, Y_Value):

    mutationResult_X = X_Value + randomNumForInput()
    mutationResult_Y = Y_Value + randomNumForInput()

    while mutationResult_X > 4 or mutationResult_X < -4:
        mutationResult_X = X_Value + randomNumForInput()

    while mutationResult_Y > 4 or mutationResult_Y < -4:
        mutationResult_Y = Y_Value + randomNumForInput()

    mutationResults = [mutationResult_X, mutationResult_Y]
    return mutationResults
```

`randomNumForInput` simply returns a random number between 4 and -4. (Interval Limits for the search.) Hence it is equivalent to `random.uniform(-4, 4)`.

This is the central function of the program.

```py
def simulated_annealing(f):
    """Peforms simulated annealing to find a solution"""
    #Start by initializing the current state with the initial state
    #acquired by a random generation of a number and then using it
    #in the noisy func, also set solution(best_state) as current_state
    #for a start
    pCurSelect  = [randomNumForInput(),randomNumForInput()]
    current_state = f(pCurSelect[0],pCurSelect[1])
    best_state = current_state
    #Begin time monitoring, this will represent the
    #Number of steps over time
    TimeStamp = 1

    #Init current temp via the func, using such values as to get the initial temp
    initial_temp = 100
    final_temp = .1
    alpha = 0.001
    num_of_steps = 1000000
    #calculates by how much the temperature should be tweaked
    #each iteration
    #suppose the number of steps is linear, we'll send in 100
    temp_Delta = calcTempDelta(initial_temp, final_temp, num_of_steps)
    #set current_temp via initial temp
    current_temp = getTemperature(initial_temp, temp_Delta)

    #max_iterations = 100
    #initial_temp = get_Temperature_Poly(TimeStamp)

    #current_temp > final_temp
    while current_temp > final_temp:
        #get a mutated value from the current value
        #hence being a 'neighbour' value
        #with it, acquire the neighbouring state
        #to the current state
        neighbour_values = mutate(pCurSelect[0], pCurSelect[1])
        neighbour_state = f(neighbour_values[0], neighbour_values[1])

        #calculate the difference between the newly mutated
        #neighbour state and the current state
        delta_E_Of_States = neighbour_state - current_state

        # Check if neighbor_state is the best state so far

        # if the new solution is better (lower), accept it
        if delta_E_Of_States <= 0:
            pCurSelect = neighbour_values
            current_state = neighbour_state
            if current_state < best_state:
                best_state = current_state

        # if the new solution is not better, accept it with a probability of e^(-cost/temp)
        else:
            if random.uniform(0, 1) < math.exp(-(delta_E_Of_States) / current_temp):
                pCurSelect = neighbour_values
                current_state = neighbour_state
        # Here, we'd decrement the temperature or increase the timestamp, normally
        """current_temp -= alpha"""

        #print("Run number: " + str(TimeStamp) + " current_state = " + str(current_state) )
        #increment TimeStamp
        TimeStamp = TimeStamp + 1

        # calc temp for next iteration
        current_temp = getTemperature(current_temp, temp_Delta)

    #print("Iteration Count: " + str(TimeStamp))
    return best_state
```

`alpha` is not used for this implementation, however temperature is moderated linearly using the following funcs:

```py
def calcTempDelta(T_Initial, T_Final, N):
    return((T_Initial-T_Final)/N)

def getTemperature(T_old, T_new):
    return (T_old - T_new)
```

This is how I implemented the solution described in page 245 of the book. However, this implementation does not return to me the global minimum of the noisy function, but rather, one of its near-by local minimum.

The reasons I implemented the solution in this way is two fold:

1. It has been provided to me as a working example of a linear temperature moderation, and thus a working template.
2. Although I have tried to understand the other forms of temperature moderation laid out in the book in pages 248-249, it is not entirely clear to me how the variable "Ts" is calculated, and even after trying to look through some of the cited sources the book references, it remains esoteric for me still. Thus I figured, I'd rather try to make this "simple" solution work correctly first, before proceeding to attempt other approaches of temperature quenching (logarithmic, exponential, etc).

Since then I have tried in numerous ways to acquire the global minimum of the noisy func through various different iterations of the code, which would be too much to post here all at once. I've tried different rewrites of this code:

1. Decrease the randomly rolled number over each iteration as in order to search within a smaller scope every time, this has resulted in more consistent but still incorrect results.
2. Mutate by different increments, so lets say, between -1 and 1, etc. Same effect.
3. Rewrite mutate as in order to examine the neighbouring points to the current point via some step size, and examine neighboring points by adding/reducing said step size from the current point's x/y values, checking the differences between the newly generated point and the current point (the delta of E's, basically), and return the appropriate values with whichever one produced the lowest distance to the current function, thus being its closest proximity neighbour.
4. Reduce the intervals limits over which the search occurs.

It is in these, the solutions involving step-size/reducing limits/checking neighbours by quadrants that I have used movements comprised of some constant alpha times the time_stamp.

These and other solutions which I've attempted have not worked, either producing even less accurate results (albeit in some cases more consistent results) or in one case, not working at all.

Therefore I must be missing something, whether its to do with the temperature moderation, or the precise way (formula) by which I'm supposed to make the next step (mutate) in the algorithm.

I know its a lot to take in and look at, but I'd appreciate any constructive criticism/help/advice you can provide me.
If it will be of any help to showcase code bits of the other solution attempts, I'll post them if asked.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you ask how to numerically find the minimum of a given function, correct?

Comment: The global minimum of the given function, which is to say, the lowest point in the entire function. The purpose of the simulated annealing is to retrieve it. The solution is already known and is documented here: https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00072116/document in page 11. The book I'm using is this one for reference: http://www.it-weise.de/projects/bookNew.pdf

Comment: This is just a heuristic (i.e. glorified trial-and-error). These methods, in general, don't find the optimal solution but rather a good solution.

Comment: From scanning the code, I feel the proposals are too coarse, try add only a little randomness to either x or y, and just clip the result to -4,4. no while loop. Also, dont spend too much time on the cooling, just the reduce with alpha (reduce with factor) is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is important that you keep track of what you are doing.
I have put a few important tips on [frigidum](https://pypi.org/project/frigidum/)

The `alpha` cooling generally works well, it makes sure you don't speed through the interesting sweet-spot, where about 0.1 of the proposals are accepted.

Make sure your proposals are not too coarse, I have put a example where I only change x or y, but never both. The idea is that annealing will take whats best, or take a tour, and let the scheme decide.

I use the package frigidum for the algo, but its pretty much the same are your code. Also notice I have 2 proposals, a large change and a small change, combinations usually work well.

Finally, I noticed its hopping a lot. A small variation would be to pick the best-so-far before you go in the last 5% of your cooling.

I use/install frigidum

```
!pip install frigidum
```

And made a small change to make use of numpy arrays;

```
import math

def noisy_func(X):
    x, y = X
    return (math.exp(math.sin(50*x)) +
            math.sin(60*math.exp(y)) +
            math.sin(70*math.sin(x)) +
            math.sin(math.sin(80*y)) -
            math.sin(10*(x + y)) +
            0.25*(math.pow(x, 2) +
            math.pow(y, 2)))


import frigidum
import numpy as np
import random

def random_start():
    return np.random.random( 2 ) * 4

def random_small_step(x):
    if np.random.random() < .5:
        return np.clip( x + np.array( [0, 0.02 * (random.random() - .5)] ), -4,4)
    else:
        return np.clip( x + np.array( [0.02 * (random.random() - .5), 0] ), -4,4)


def random_big_step(x):
    if np.random.random() < .5:
        return np.clip( x + np.array( [0, 0.5 * (random.random() - .5)] ), -4,4)
    else:
        return np.clip( x + np.array( [0.5 * (random.random() - .5), 0] ), -4,4)

local_opt = frigidum.sa(random_start=random_start, 
                        neighbours=[random_small_step, random_big_step], 
                        objective_function=noisy_func, 
                        T_start=10**2, 
                        T_stop=0.00001, 
                        repeats=10**4, 
                        copy_state=frigidum.annealing.copy)
```

---

The output of the above was

```
---
Neighbour Statistics: 
(proportion of proposals which got accepted *and* changed the objective function)
   random_small_step                : 0.451045
   random_big_step                  : 0.268002
---
(Local) Minimum Objective Value Found: 
   -3.30669277
```

With the above code sometimes I get below -3, but I also noticed sometimes it has found something around -2, than it is stuck in the last phase.

So a small tweak would be to re-anneal the last phase of the annealing, with the best-found-so-far.

Hope that helps, let me know if any questions.

Comment: forgot to mention, there is a alpha used by default, you can change it with `alpha=.9`

Comment: I've tried using your suggestion, however, theres two issues. The first is that Im unfamiliar with this library so, I dont quite get how to reanneal it. Secondly, I've tried to arrive at a working solution via implementing my own so that I may understand the procedure in its smallest details. I'm sorry for not responding recently as I had my primary pc die as a result of running this project (blew out the gpu/motherboard). I hope to get back to work on it and potentially find a working solution tomorrow, we'll see.

Comment: No worries. You can look at frigidum for tips, for instance keep track of accepted states for each batch, a very important metric